# ManyToManyToMany Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, annotations, many-to-many

I've been trying to solved this issue about the Doctrine configuration I have set with three Entities in Symfony2 (v2.3.9)

Let's assume my application's goal is to manage the enrollment of certain people to different training courses. And I do want to split these courses in different groups: A, B and C.

So, my entities are:

- Enrollment
- Course
- Group

The enrollment of a certain person can be to more than one course, but he/she cannot enroll to the same Course in different groups. That means, having some sort of table which looks like this one:

```
----------------------------------------
| enrollment_id | course_id | group_id |
----------------------------------------
|       1       |     1     |    1     |
----------------------------------------
|       1       |     2     |    3     |
----------------------------------------
```

So far, I've been able to create a ManyToMany relationship between the Enrollment entity and the Course entity.

```
Enrollment.php

...
/**
 * 
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Course", inversedBy="enrollments")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="enrollment_course",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="enrollment_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="course_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 *
 */
protected $courses;
.....
```

And the Course entity looks like this in terms of relationship:

```
Course.php
....

/**
 * 
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Enrollment", mappedBy="courses")
 */

protected $enrollments;
....
```

That makes the configuration incomplete.

```
-----------------------------
| enrollment_id | course_id |
-----------------------------
|       1       |     1     |
-----------------------------
|       1       |     2     |
-----------------------------
```

Considering the fact that, in order to complete the enrollment, I need both informations the Course and the Group. How can I translate this into Doctrine annotation?

Do you have any clue?

Thank you so much for your help.

Dani.

Comment: You probably need a custom entity with some validation rules as opposed to a straight database constraint rule, which is what the doctrine annotation you hint at will accomplish.  That being said, I'm not sure how to write such a table via doctrine.

Answer (score 0):

You need a make an entity for the sole purpose of joining the fields.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="base",uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="enrollment_course_group_idx", columns={"enrollment_id", "course_id", "group_id"})})
 */
class Base
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Enrollment")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="enrollment_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    private $enrollment;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="course")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="course_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    private $course;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Group")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    private $group;
```

Comment: Thanks, Derick. I'll try and come back to you. Thanks again for your help.